# Can I disable Health Checks Sqlite healthchecksdb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, health-check

Im using Net Core (2.1) Health Checks and HealthChecks-UI (https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks). I dont want to use the Sqlite healthchecksdb. Is there a way to disable it and do not use it?

Answer (score 1):

The following will disable the default sqlite configuration.

```
services.AddHealthChecksUI().AddInMemoryStorage();
```

https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#UI-Storage-Providers

Answer (score 0):

Currrently the newest version supports specify the db path for Sqlite , but still doesn't support saving to sqlite on memory or use other data provider like Sql Server .

You can trace the process in Github issues :

https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/29

Comment: Hi, Do you know why is necessary use this db? (I dont want the health history)

Comment: Why do you want that feature , Anyway , you can leave comment on that github issue for quick and offical response.